# Web development environment for small team doing small projects

Tags: php, mysql, git, svn, ftp

Currently, I'm working freelance and doing small projects (i.e. about 1 week to 1 month) for my customers. I use tools like FTP to upload/download files; setup a local web and database server for some projects; sometimes use Git or SVN for bigger projects. But most of the time, I just use FTP. This works just fine for me.

But now I'm planning to expand my work and may hire 1 or 2 programmers. Most of my works will be PHP/MySQL. What setting will be more suitable for my team? I goal is to minimize the configuration time.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure this is entirely suitable question for SO, and is quite open ended as plenty of people will have different solutions, here is one way of doing what you ask

Use Virtual Box & Vagrant along with Chef or Puppet to ensure all developers have identical development environments.

Then use Git via a central remote repo (i.e Github, BitBucket, custom) to collaborate.

Comment: Thank you. I will try these virtual environments to see if they can fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have idea about GIT then Its better, you can make some more research there are some functions like branching, all of your team member can work on different branches and finally you can merge them